# 'MapEditServiceConfig' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, typescript

Not sure why this error is prompting for MapEditServiceConfig , saying MapEditServiceConfig refers to a type , also what do we understand as 
MapEditServiceConfig {}, as MapEditServiceConfig is a interface, what this bracket says?

```
export interface MapEditServiceConfig extends AppCredentialsConfig {
    readonly "moderation.authServiceId": string;
    readonly "maphub.mc.endpoint": string;
}

export interface AppConfig
    extends MapDataServiceConfig,
        GeocoderConfig,
        LoginServiceConfig,
        ScbeServiceConfig,
        MapJobServiceConfig,
        TaskProviderServiceConfig,
        YourXYZSpaceServiceConfig {

                       "map.defaultLocation":MapDataModels.MapLocation;
            "app.imageBasePath": string;
        },
        MapEditServiceConfig {}  // Getting the refers to a //type , but use as a value here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list of interfaces the `AppConfig` extends there is this part:

```
 {
   "map.defaultLocation":MapDataModels.MapLocation;
   "app.imageBasePath": string;
},
```

that is interpreted by the compiler as the actual definition of the `AppConfig` interface.

The comma is a syntax error, the compiler expects a declaration.

After that follows a new statement `MapEditServiceConfig` which is interpreted by the compiler as an literal value.